# Receving a value from AXI connected to UART

Tags: c, fpga, uart, xilinx-ise, spartan

On ISE 14.7, what do I need to do in order to have the AXI stream (which has an ipcore that loops a value) to give me output via the UART?

I had set up the project properly, added a UART and set the mhs, ucf files and the rest of the bonanza, however I do not have any idea what do I need to do to have output from the AXI via the UART.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you following some sort of guide for this?

Comment: Just a coursework assignment, no guide for, not even a clue on how to start it. It is a bit of a try and guess situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write an UART module in RTL or use an existing Ip-core which accepts AXI-stream transaction and converts it to UART messages.

However due to performance differences it is more common to find IP-cores with AXI4-Lite interface to UART. For example AXI UART 16550  (https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_uart16550/v2_0/pg143-axi-uart16550.pdf)

Comment: I will try it out now!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is wrong ? which IP are you using ? what is the error message ?

Comment: The IP I am to use a is custom made one and by the looks of it, it has been produced in Matlab.

Comment: In the *.h file it just has some address values in hex (e.g #define IPCore_Enable_const_axi_ip 0x4). Perhaps I would need to use them in some way?